# How to set the HTML select options from a json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got one external .json file, in which a arry is defined as:

```
var words = [
    "a",
    "able",
    "about",
    "account",
    "acid",
    "across",
    "act",
    "addition"]
```

My plan is to import in  the .json file via jquery, and then use the values in the array `word` as the `option` in a `select` object.
My understanding is:

```
<div>
    <select size="7" class="selection"></select>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("words-small.json", function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (i, word) {
                $(".selection").html("<option>word</option>");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

or:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("words-small.json", function (result) {
            html = ''
            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                html += "<option value=" + result[i] + ">" + result[i] + "</option>";
            };
            document.getElementById("myselect").innerHTML = html;
        });
    });
</script>
```

But neither works here. Please tell me how to fix that.

Comment: you are receiving a file where the array was declared.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy So you mean I could directly use the imported json as a object? Sorry I am not quite clear what you indicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36139705/1209018 This answer explains what I was trying to explain.

Comment: Your second block looks close to correct, there is a misspelling in your for loop, it should be `i < result.length` if that doesn't work I assume the file is not being retrieved correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.json`-file needs to be like this:

```
[
    "a",
    "able",
    "about",
    "account",
    "acid",
    "across",
    "act",
    "addition"
]
```

Then either of the scripts should work. (First one with one small adjustment)

```
<div>
    <select size="7" class="selection"></select>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("words-small.json", function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (i, word) {
                $(".selection").append("<option>"+word+"</option>");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Remember that a .json-file should only contain JSON. Not javascript which is what you had.

Comment: @Ishas, your method should work; however, it doesn't work until I declare a var in the `script`.
    `<script>
        var result;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("words-small.json", function (result) {
                $.each(result, function (i, word) {
                    $(".selection").html("<option>"+word+"</option>");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>`

Comment: You saved me! it works

Answer (score 1):

You have some typos in your code.

Assuming that you have valid json and parsed `words` array

```js
var words = [
    "a",
    "able",
    "about",
    "account",
    "acid",
    "across",
    "act",
    "addition"];

$.each(words, function (i, word) {
   $(".selection").append("<option value='"+word+"'>" + word + "</option>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select size="7" class="selection"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Your method works. But in fact the `.json` file contains a large array, so I must use `$.getJSON` to read it in. Meanwhile I have to declare the `var` before it, and that is so wield.

Comment: @BsHe It's just an example, I showed you how to make `options`. Of course you should to parse your json to get `words` array.

Answer (score 0):

For your first attempt, you're doing:

```
$(".selection").html("<option>word</option>");
```

You should be using something like append, and also make sure you take "word" out of the quotes:

```
$(".selection").append("<option>" + word + "</option">);
```

.html() just replaces the data contained within the HTML element, whereas .append() will add them to the end.

This is the issue if you're only getting one value returned.

It looks like in your JSON object you have the data defined in a variable, instead it should just be:

```
[
    "a",
    "able",
    "about",
    "account",
    "acid",
    "across",
    "act",
    "addition"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me:

```
$.each(words, function (i, word) {
    items+="<option>"+word+"</option>";
});
$(".selection").html(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several things that need to be fixed. One, is that .html() replaces the innerHTML, doesn't add to it. So, you need to build all the options and then set them. I also, as you had in the second script, put the value of the word as the option value. Note, the inner quotes are also needed. Furthermore, your jQuery of ".selection" will do this to **all** objects designated with the "selection" class, whereas, in your second script, you seemed to want to only assign **one** element with an id of "myselect".

```
<div>
   <select size="7" class="selection"></select>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("words-small.json", function (result) {
            var html = "";
            $.each(result, function (i, word) {
                html += "<option value='"+word+"'>"+word+"</option");
            });
            $(".selection").html(html);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend jQuery. The best thing about this approach is you can reuse these extensions when needing to clear or fill a select.  Just pass it an array.

```
$.fn.clearSelect = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (this.tagName == 'SELECT')
            this.options.length = 0;
    });
}

$.fn.fillSelect = function(data) {
    return this.clearSelect().each(function() {
        if (this.tagName == 'SELECT') {
            var dropdownList = this;
            if (data.length > 0) {
                this.disabled = false;
            }

            $.each(data, function(index, optionData) {
                var option = new Option(optionData, optionData);

                dropdownList.add(option, null);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This extension will allow you to pass your data directly to the select like this

```
$("#myselectid").fillselect(["a","able","about","account","acid","across","act"]);
```

I have not tested this, but the snip-it should give you the general idea.

But in your example you could call the extensions this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("words-small.json", function (result) {
           $(".selection").fillSelect(result);
        }
});
```

Just tested and edited the snipet.  Test is located here https://jsfiddle.net/4wmj8pkk/